# Driver Attention Monitoring System for Kinect v2

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, sdk, kinect-v2

I'm doing a project on Kinect V2 about Driver Monitoring System. The summary of the project is to focus on driver biological measures that is to track the head position and eyes expression. Driver inattention monitoring can be classified into distraction and fatigue and is a main factor in most traffic accidents. So by creating a GUI that able to detect the driver in real time and also alert the driver when they are sleeping or not paying attention while driving the car. Does anyone have done a similar project that can share with me or give me some guide on how to start? Thank you!